# Vectorized assignment of columns to a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing ***i*** rows and ***j*** columns. I want to replace values in this DataFrame with all values from a second DataFrame that has the same ***i*** rows but ***k*** columns, where ***k*** is a subset of ***j***.

What works is this:

```
for col in df2.columns:
    df1[col] = df2[col]
```

Is there a faster, non-loopy way of doing this?

Comment: you should be able to just do `df1[df2.columns] = df2`

Comment: why didn't i think of this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can just do

```
df1[df2.columns] = df2
```

assuming index and column labels match as you stated

Here we take a subset of `df1` passing just the columns of interest, so long as the index and column labels match you can just directly assign like so.
There is no need to iterate here

If the index labels don't match but the shape does you can assign the numpy array values:

```
df1[df2.columns] = df2.values
```

This will assign the values as raw values, it's possible that this method will be faster as `pandas` doesn't need to check alignment with index labels or column labels and should be able to just directly assign

Comment: for my use case where n_rows = 8500, n_cols = 2500 and n_cols_subset = 2300 the first snippet was just as fast as my loop. The second approach however was 5x faster and exactly what I was looking for. thanks.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me, so long as you have homogenous dtypes, and the shape matches then you can just directly assign using the numpy array